# Convert JSON to relational database format table (with repeating values) PHP

Tags: php, json

I'm sure there's a proper name for that operation, but I couldn't find it.
Well, what I'm looking for is a PHP function to convert a JSON data (decoded to a associative array) like this:

```
{
    "id": 768570754,
    "status": "paid",
    "status_detail": null,
    "date_created": "2013-05-27T10:01:50.000-04:00",
    "date_closed": "2013-05-27T10:04:07.000-04:00",
    "order_items": [{
        "item": {
            "id": "MLB12345678",
            "title": "Samsung Galaxy",
            "variation_id": null,
            "variation_attributes": []
        },
        "quantity": 1,
        "unit_price": 499,
        "currency_id": "BRL"
    }]
}
```

To a table format with those columns, where some data may repeat itself if there's more than one row present in its child:

```
id | status | status_detail | date_created | date_closed | item_id | item_title | item_variation_id | quantity | unit_price
```

I wanted to this as a standard procedure to fit in any JSON data, whatever nested arrays are found.

Is there a pre-build function in PHP to handle that?

Comment: the short answer is no, and what you are creating is not a relational database

Comment: Thanks! Yes, I understand it's not a relational database. Just tried to ilustrate what I was trying to do.

Comment: There's no pre-built function for this, I'm afraid. The only way I could think of is to create a table which stores each key-value pair as a seperate row. But that's very inefficient. Do you want me to elaborate?

Comment: Thank you @ManuelOtto! Well, I'm thinking of creating an separate array for each nested array and then merging them, but doing that like a cross join. This step can be done before commiting anything to the database...

Comment: Well, I could try to hack something together. Is the 'id' the primary key of your datasets, in other words, Is it always present and used to find the dataset?

Comment: What if an order has multiple items?

Comment: I would try to use point-notation in the key field. e.g. 'order_items.item.id' and then rebuild the array with php.

Comment: Actually, this data can change and I wanted to have something standard, that could be used with any JSON data... If an order has multiple items, they should repeat the info that is "unique" in this JSON structure, like a denormalized table...

Comment: That's what I'm talking about. Apologies, I meant 'order_items.0.item.id'

Comment: Good. I'll try something like that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For storing this is what I've come up with:

You're gonna need a table with the following structure

```
VARCHAR (id)
VARCHAR (key)
VARCHAR (value)
```

I've named it 'productmeta', but it doesnt matter.

And then you should be able to store an arbitrary dataset with the following code by calling `storeDataset(DATA);`

```
function storeDataset($data){
    if(!isset($data['id'])){ // check for id
        throw new Exception('Missing ID field from dataset');
        return;
    }
    // extract id
    $id = $data['id'];
    unset($data['id']);

    // get key value pairs recursively
    $pairs = getKeyValPairs($data,'');

    $sql_parts = array();
    for($i=0;$i<count($pairs);$i++){
        $key = $pairs[$i]['key'];
        $value = $pairs[$i]['value'];
        $sql_parts[] = "($id, '$key', '$value')";
    }

    $sql_data = implode(',', $sql_parts);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO productmeta (`id`,`key`,`value`) VALUES '.$sql_data;

    // TODO: execute $sql

}

function getKeyValPairs($arr,$level){
    $pairs = array();
    foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
        if(is_array($value))
            $pairs = array_merge($pairs,getKeyValPairs($value,$level.$key.'.'));
        else
            $pairs[] = array('key'=>$level.$key,'value'=>$value);
    }
    return $pairs;
}
```

Currently trying to code the reading part...

Comment: Thank you Manuel! I think I got your logic here... But then I'll have to transpose the 'rows' (key) to 'columns', and the 'id' part is just an sample of the data... It may happen that the 'id' may change it's name to 'user_id' or be missing...

Comment: Hmm, but then, how are you going to find any datasets anyway? They must have an identifier otherwise you cant really perform any operations...

Comment: Anyways, this is the only way to do it with mysql as far is I know. Mysql just aint built for that kind of task. If you want, I can code the read/update part, otherwise I'm glad I could help :)

Comment: Sorry Manuel, I think your solution is the way to go to store the data... It's just that I wanted to show this information to the user before inserting it. To be more specific this data comes from an API, and I wanted to build that on charts that require a "table-like" data, but after that, I'll use your logic here to save the data. Inserting, then reading it isn't viable for what I'm building here, but I'm very grateful for your help!

Comment: Oh now I get it. The tag 'mysql' made it look like it was a database thing. So you're basically looking for a html representation of the data?

Comment: Sorry about that tag Manuel. Yes, something like this! But, as mentioned before, I'm looking for something that could handle any JSON data (flexible) and repeat the values, when there's an "one to many relation". So if there's two order_items for one id, it should show a table where id repeats...

Comment: Ok, but you can actually use the 'getKeyValPairs()' function for that. It will return the dataset as a flattened array. Do you want me to update that?

Comment: Good one! Haven't tried the function! If you have something in mind to turn order_items.0.item.title to order_items.item.title (a single column with the values inside) and to repeat the others, I'll be very thankful...

Comment: So the value field should contain all the values of the same type delimited by a semicolon, or comma, or what?

Comment: I'm looking for a result like this (assuming we have more than one order, in order_items) [0] => [ 'id' => 'XXXX', 'order_items.item.title' => 'Samsung A' ], [1] =>  [ 'id' => 'XXXX', 'order_items.item.title' => 'Samsung B' ]. Don't know if I'm explaining well...

Comment: Ok, so it should create copies for each item, with the same date_created, status, etc?

Comment: Yes. That's it! I'm trying something around your code. You've been already of great help! Thanks

Comment: Ok, now I've got you! :D give me some time. It's a very different approach.